# Insert information from cells to combobox

Tags: excel, vb.net, combobox, basic

I am not sure what went wrong with the code but it worked before, I've only added 3 more lines in the top. I know it's not perfect and it can be done better, I appreciate the help!

Logic:
I would like for the code to read from cell A5 till the end of the sheet, and put them into combobox to chose from.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim cntr As Integer
cntr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
For i = 6 + i To cntr
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem Cells(i, 1)


Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What were the **only added 3 more lines in the top** ?

Comment: Hello,
Okay I've manage to figure out the error - it works now almost perfect. I just need to read more about the Range. Thanks for help!

Comment: Hello, they were empty lines where I placed 2 buttons.